# JavaScript window.location.replace(url) Reloading Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, jquery

my aim is to create a script which will redirect the user from the home page to the relevant language page based on their browser language, here is what I have so far:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
        if (language === "en-US") {
            window.location.replace("/test")
        }
    });
</script>
```

The issue is that when the `/test` page loads, it will reload several times before finally stopping. Please see below to see this in action (only works if browser language is "en-US")

http://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/

Could anybody please advise where this is going wrong and why the location is being replaced multiple times? Apologies in advance, I've only just began to learn coding. Thank you for your time.

Comment: i'd guess the same script is also present on the page you're redirecting to? which would cause an infinite loop before something goes wrong and the redirects stop? you could try to determine the location before redirecting so that the location isn't modified if the user is already on the target site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your code is wrapped in the `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` each time the page is loaded, your `window.location.replace` is called and starts the page refresh.

I did notice that you had a language dropdown on your site, so maybe try something similar to this instead:

`<select class="foo" id="bar" onchange="dropdownChange()">
//options here
</select>`

and your javscript to

`function dropdownChange() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("bar");
    var language = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    if (language === "en-US") {
        window.location.replace("/test");
    }
}`

Comment: I didn't think about using the drop-down but now you've mentioned it, this would be absolutely perfect because the functionality is already built into the platform. I'll take a look at this code above, will it select the drop-down option instead of redirecting itself?

Comment: @matt136 You will have to make sure that the value's of the dropdown are set to the values you are checking in the if statement but the code will only cause the page to refresh once a different value is selected.

Answer (score -1):

I tried your link in chrome and I could not see the multiple loads.
Which browser are you using?

Comment: It's not an answer, please use comment section

Comment: I'm sorry I was being stupid, it will only work for "en-US" at the moment.